# ComponentRegistration.Add is obsolete

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

We developed a chatbot with the Microsoft botframework. We used the method ComponentRegistration.Add to register some Adaptive Classes. Now the method is obsolete and we are looking for a replacement of that obsolete code:

```
// Register dialog. This sets up memory paths for adaptive.
ComponentRegistration.Add(new DialogsComponentRegistration());

// Register adaptive component
ComponentRegistration.Add(new AdaptiveComponentRegistration());

// Register declarative components for adaptive dialogs.
ComponentRegistration.Add(new DeclarativeComponentRegistration());

// Register to use language generation.
ComponentRegistration.Add(new LanguageGenerationComponentRegistration());

// Register luis component
ComponentRegistration.Add(new LuisComponentRegistration());
```

Do you have an idea, how to replace this code by using the resource explorer?
Regards
Andreas